# Is there a way to make clicking a button in Adobe Flash open multiple hyperlinks?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Simply put, is there a way to make clicking a button object in Flash Actionscript 3.0 open two hyperlinks in a browser? I've tried messing with the Actionscript and adding multiple functions, to no avail.

Comment: Hi, please take a look at this, it may help you find what you're looking for. http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3link/  EDIT - I would try and give an answer, but do not have Flash Develop installed, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use two different `window` strings:

```
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561823/is-there-a-way-to-make-clicking-a-button-in-adobe-flash-open-multiple-hyperlinks");
navigateToURL(url, "_blank");
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
navigateToURL(url, "_blank2");
```

#### Note:

For local content (via `file://`) running in a browser, `navigateToURL` will not work unless your html/swf is in the local-trusted security sandbox.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I wanted!